# Liquibase run changeset every time

Tags: java, liquibase

I want to insert usernames to the database based on a system property. The system property value can be

> users="user1;user2;user3"

This process must be repeatable, meaning that every time the applications is deployed, the migration/changeset must check the system property, and if it has changed and the users are not already in the database it should insert them. In order to achieve this I am thinking of using the [customChange](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/custom_change.html) tag. But I want this change to run every time the liquibase runs. Is this possible using liquibase or should I create a custom contextLoadListener?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A standard attribute available to all changesets is the `runAlways` attribute, which should do what you want. There is also a `runOnChange` attribute available.

Documentation on the attributes available is here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html